# Python, как отследить изменение файла?

Tags: python

Мне нужно отследить изменение конкретного файла по конкретному пути(именно факт того что файл изменили, а не сами изменения), я написал код:

```
import os
import shutil
import time

class someclass:
    def __init__(self):
        if not os.path.isdir("temp"):
            os.mkdir("temp")
            os.chdir("temp")
        else:
            os.chdir("temp")

    def watch_file_update(self, filepath):
        if os.path.exists(filepath):
            # Копирую файл в temp
            shutil.copy(filepath, os.getcwd())
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
                if not os.path.exists(filepath):
                    # Если в процессе файл удалят, переименуют или ещё что, то я возвращаю -2
                    return -2
                else:
                    # Сравниваю файл в temp с оригиналом 
                    with open(filepath, 'r') as f1:
                        with open(f'{os.getcwd()}/{os.path.basename(filepath)}', 'r') as f2:
                            if not f1.read() == f2.read():
                                return 1
        else:
            return -1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    api = someclass()
    if api.watch_file_update("D:/somefile.txt") == 1:
        # Сделать что-либо
    elif api.watch_file_update("D:/somefile.txt") == -1:
        print("Ошибка, файл не найден")
    elif api.watch_file_update("D:/somefile.txt") == -2:
        print("Ошибка, возможно файл был перемещён или удалён")
```

Код абсолютно рабочий, только есть одна загвоздка, он подходит разве что для файлов меньше 1мб, иначе же он жрёт невероятно много ресурсов компа и работает невероятно медленно, может есть какой-то другой способ   отследить изменение файла, или может существует волшебная библиотека для отслеживания изменения файла?

Comment: Теоретически, это можно достаточно просто сделать на pyqt с помощью QFileSystemWatcher. Похожее я делал с помощью Qt на C++. С другой стороны, тянуть за собой pyqt только ради этого выглядит как-то сомнительно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сравнивать не содержимое файлов, а дату последнего редактирования файла. Её можно получить с помощью модуля `os`:

```
import os

def watch_file_update(path):
  timestamp = os.stat(path).st_mtime
  while 1:
    if timestamp != os.stat(path).st_mtime:
      timestamp = os.stat(path).st_mtime
      print('Файл изменён!') 
      return

watch_file_update("D:/somefile.txt")
```

Comment: только нужно помнить, что эту дату можно изменить на совершенно любую, даже на ту, которая была до этого. Более того, есть программы, которые изменяя файл, не изменяют эту дату.

Answer (score 4):

Или использовать md5 хеширование. Памяти жрет немного и будете точно уверены, что файлы идентичен. Но если это не принципиально, то лучше использовать первый вариант, так как более простой и быстрый

```py
import hashlib

with open("your_filename.png", "rb") as f:
    file_hash = hashlib.md5()
    while chunk := f.read(8192):
        file_hash.update(chunk)

print(file_hash.digest())
print(file_hash.hexdigest())
```